# How can I crop image after uploading in react js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

**How can I crop image after uploading in react js?**

Hello there, how can I crop or modify the image after uploading or before? I wanna crop it in a constant aspect ratio but I don't know how to make it.
I tried to use react-easy-crop but I still don't know to implement it. anyone may help me?

```js
import React from "react";
import { Uploader, Icon, Alert, Loader, ControlLabel } from "rsuite";
import localStorage from "../../utils/lib/local-storage";
const dataUser = localStorage().get("auth");

const previewFile = (file, callback) => {
    const reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onloadend = () => {
        callback(reader.result);
    };
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
};

const Avatar = ({
    image = false,
    styles = {
        width: 120,
        height: 120,
        margin: 0,
        borderRadius: "50%",
        border: "1px solid #ddd"
    },
    label = false,
    urlUpload = "/users/set-avatar"
}) => {
    const [uploading, setUploading] = React.useState(false);
    const [fileInfo, setFileInfo] = React.useState(image);

    return (
        <div style={{ marginBottom: label ? 15 : 0 }}>
            {label && <ControlLabel>{label}</ControlLabel>}
            <Uploader
                fileListVisible={false}
                listType="picture"
                onUpload={file => {
                    setUploading(true);
                    previewFile(file.blobFile, value => {
                        setFileInfo(value);
                    });
                }}
                onSuccess={response => {
                    setUploading(false);
                    Alert.success("Uploaded successfully");
                    window.location.reload();
                }}
                onError={() => {
                    setFileInfo(null);
                    setUploading(false);
                    Alert.error("Upload failed");
                }}
                name="images"
                action={${process.env.REACT_APP_BASE_URL}${urlUpload}}
                headers={{
                    Authorization: "Bearer " + dataUser.token
                }}
            >
                <button type="button" style={styles}>
                    {uploading && <Loader backdrop center />}
                    {fileInfo ? (
                        <img
                            src={fileInfo}
                            alt="avatar"
                            width="100%"
                            height="100%"
                        />
                    ) : (
                        <Icon icon="avatar" size="5x" />
                    )}
                </button>
            </Uploader>
        </div>
    );
};
export default Avatar;
```

in my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the image inside a container div of the dimensions you want the image to be cropped to. Then give the container a style of overflow: “hidden”.